# Orderby custom field for custome post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I am trying to order a custom post type called "Teachers" by a field called sort_by.  I am not sure why this isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'teacher', 'posts_per_page' => 30, 'order_by' => 'sort_by' ,'order'=>'ASC' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<div class="entry-content"><h2 class="teachers">';
    the_title();
    echo '</h2>';
    the_excerpt();
    echo  '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is `orderby` not `order_by` but I am not sure what `sort_by` is. If that is a custom meta field you need to alter the query.

> 'meta_value' - Note that a 'meta_key=keyname' must also be present in
>   the query. Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is
>   fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g.
>   1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might
>   naturally expect). Use 'meta_value_num' instead for numeric values.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

You need to pass one argument for the meta_key and another for the `orderby`.

```
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'teacher',
  'posts_per_page' => 30,
  'meta_key' => 'sort_by',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order'=>'ASC' 
);
```

Comment: If this solved the question please mark it as "Accepted". Look for the check mark on the left.