# WordPress Not Sorting By Custom Field

Tags: loop, order

I am trying to sort by a custom taxonomy, which is a rating, in my WordPress loop, however it is not sorting by number.  If I sort by order 'ASC' then it will put those without a rating at the top - otherwise no ordering either by 'ASC' or 'DESC'.

Any ideas please?

```
$number = 1;
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'rating', 'order' => 'ASC' ); 
    $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post();

if (has_term( 'Roast Dinner', 'type')) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $number . '. '; $number++;?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <span class="remove-link"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'rating', '' )); ?></span>
        <span class="remove-link league-table-price hidden"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'price', '' )); ?></span>
        <span class="remove-link league-table-priceincservice hidden"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'priceincservice', '' )); ?></span>
        <span class="remove-link league-table-meat hidden"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'meat', '' )); ?></span>
        <span class="remove-link league-table-tubeline hidden"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'tubeline', '' )); ?></span>
        <span class="remove-link league-table-tubestation hidden"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'tubestation', '' )); ?></span>
        <span class="remove-link league-table-areaoflondon hidden"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'areaoflondon', '' )); ?></span>
        <span class="remove-link league-table-districtoflondon hidden"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'districtoflondon', '' )); ?></span>
        <span class="remove-link league-table-zone hidden"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'zone', '' )); ?></span>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Edit - I did try the solution shown in [Orderby custom field for custome post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103988/orderby-custom-field-for-custome-post-type) however it provides a blank loop - no output.

Kind regards
James

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Orderby custom field for custome post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103988/orderby-custom-field-for-custome-post-type)

Comment: Sigh the SO downvoters are out again.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters). `'rating'` is not a valid value for `orderby`. To sort by a custom field you need to use `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` or `'meta_value_num'`.

> Note that a ‘meta_key=keyname‘ must also be present in the query. Note
>   also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is fine for strings
>   (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g. 1, 3, 34, 4, 56,
>   6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might naturally expect).
>   Use ‘meta_value_num‘ instead for numeric values. You may also specify
>   ‘meta_type‘ if you want to cast the meta value as a specific type.
>   Possible values are ‘NUMERIC’, ‘BINARY’, ‘CHAR’, ‘DATE’, ‘DATETIME’,
>   ‘DECIMAL’, ‘SIGNED’, ‘TIME’, ‘UNSIGNED’, same as in ‘$meta_query‘.

So your query would be:

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'       => 'rating',
    'order'          => 'ASC'
);
```

Note that items without a rating will be missing from this query. To include them please see this previous question and answer on the topic: 
[Orderby meta_value only returns posts that have existing meta_key](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188287/orderby-meta-value-only-returns-posts-that-have-existing-meta-key)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I did try this earlier on and it returns an empty loop.  Any further suggestions?

Comment: This is correct. Your problem is something else. I notice you're not specifying a post type. Are you querying posts or a custom post type?

Comment: I am querying posts, but ordering by custom taxonomy that is set in the post.  I hope that makes sense - I am no WordPress expert.

Comment: Ahhhh - just realised I am trying to sort by custom taxonomy - not custom field as stated in my question.

Comment: Well if you're using data for sorting, you should make it meta. It's not possible to sort by taxonomy term this way. See this question and answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy

Comment: Oh that is so much easier than what I was trying to do.  Thanks.